# Multiplying items in an array and finding the sum of the multiplied result for all rows in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anytime I click the button below it calls the populateGridWithSelectedData method.

```
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick= {this.populateGridWithSelectedData} >ADD</Button>


    populateGridWithSelectedData(){         

            let items = [...this.state.items];
            items.push({
                invoiceLine: this.state.concatenatedInvoiceLine,
                settledQuantity: this.state.settledQuantity,
                price: this.state.unitPrice,
                creditedQuantity: this.state.creditedQuantity,
                reasonCode: this.state.reasonCode
            });

            this.setState({
                items,
                invoiceLine: '',
                settledQuantity:'',
                price:'',
                creditedQuantity:'',
                reasonCode:''
            });                        
        }
```

I am pushing data into an array. This can be a lot of data. 
I want to be able to do the following on every push

1. multiply price and creditedquantity. store the result somewhere for that row, do
   the same thing for all rows added and at the end of the day find the total of this multiplication
   for all the rows.

This does not seem to be working.

```
    var total = 0;
    var multipliedResult = 0;

    for (var x in items){
        multipliedResult = (price * creditedQuantity);
        total = (total + multipliedResult);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be better:

```
var total = 0;
items.forEach(item => {
   let multipliedResult = (item.price * item.creditedQuantity)
   total += multipliedResult
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`for in` loops are for objects. You have an array. You're looking for `for of`

```
    for (var x of items){
        multipliedResult = (price * creditedQuantity);
        total = (total + multipliedResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array, yet you're not using any values of the array. You have two choices - an ordinary `for` loop iterating over the length of the array:

```
for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
    multipliedResult = price * creditedQuantity;
    total += multipliedResult;
}
```

Or a `forEach` loop with no parameters:

```
items.forEach(() => {
    multipliedResult = price * creditedQuantity;
    total += multipliedResult;
})
```